# Print a pattern in C

Tags: c

I wish to print a pattern in C language like this:

```
1
2  6
3  7  10
4  8  11  13
5  9  12  14  15
```

Currently I have this:

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {   
        for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {   
            if(i>=j)
            {
                printf(" %d ",j+i-1);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am not getting the desired result.Please can anybody help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically if you analyze the difference between numbers at each row:

```
    1  
    2  6  
    3  7  10  
    4  8  11  13  
    5  9  12  14  15  
       ^   ^  ^   ^
diff   4   3  2   1
```

Then for each column (except the first one which is equal to the row) the formula is:

```
      col_value = val(row, col-1) + (5-col))
```

For example, the last row:

```
    5  9  12  14  15  

    9 = 5 + (5-1)
    12 = 9 + (5-2)
    14 = 12 + (5-3)
    15 = 14 + (5-4)
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i,j,k;
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
  {
    k = i;
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", k);
      k += 5-j;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the above code worked ..but i am not able to understand the code..can u plz xplain it to me

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
int main()
{
int i,j;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    int temp = 4;
    int sum = 0;
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if (j == 1)
            sum = i;
        else{
            sum = sum + temp --;
        }
        printf("%d ",sum);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main () {
    int k,i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
        k = i;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf ("%d ", k);
            k = k + (5-j);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

The logic is quite straight forward.

1) The number of elements in a row equals the row number. Hence use the inner loop with j = 1 to j <= i

2) If you see the pattern you observe that every row starts with the number equals to the row index, the next number is +4 and then +3 and so on.

3) Hence use k = k + (5-j)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int i,j,temp=0,l;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    l=4;
    temp = i;
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(j>1)
        {
            printf("%d\t",temp+l);
            temp = temp+l;
            l=l-1;
        }
        else
            printf("%d\t",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```